# Ms Access Query and Reports creation

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

I currently creating a database the purpose of which is log the number of times a person does a certain procedure. They are marked on these procedures with either an N B or C.

I have created the database and the following query which will count the amount of times they receive either and N B or C.

```
TRANSFORM Count(ed.[Entry ID]) AS [CountOfEntry ID]
SELECT ap.AdultProcedureName, ap.Target, Count(ed.[Entry ID]) AS [Total Of Entry ID]
FROM tblAdultProcedures AS ap LEFT JOIN tblEntryData AS ed ON ap.AdultProcedureName = ed.[Adult Procedure]
GROUP BY ap.AdultProcedureName, ap.Target
PIVOT ed.Grade;
```

I have then created a report which will display the results of this query and work out the % of the score for N B and C.

The problem I am having is that if there is not data for any of the grade scores (N B or C)
which are column headings in my report there will be a error the report will not display. Is there any way I can write into the query or report to create the columns N B and C even if there is not data to display.

Here are screen shots of my database. 
http://www.flickr.com/photos/mattcripps/6684779281/

Thanks in advance

Comment: I thought you were only interested in returning this data for the columns (N, B, C). If so and there is no data for any of them; then what is the purpose of trying to produce the report?

Comment: @MattDonnan Yes If there is no data for any then obviously I don't want a report but if a person as done 10 dif procedures and only received the grade N then the report will not run as there are no values for the B and C colunm

Comment: Looking at the crosstab SQL above, it shouldn't make the report fail if you only have values for grade N, as you are specifying the Grade column as a whole and not separately for each type, so it should still pivot and perhaps only report 1 row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I recall, just adding IN should fix it:

```
<...>
PIVOT ed.Grade IN ("N","B","C");
```

Comment: thanks very much, that was much simpler than I thought it would be